# boto3 KeyConditionExpression on both partition and sort key

Tags: python, boto3, dynamodb-queries

So i have the following schema:

`domain` (partition key)

`time_stamp` (sort key)

I am (attempting) to use boto to query dynamo. I want to return all records with a given `domain`, after a given `time_stamp`.

I have tried a couple of different approaches to no avail:

First is my ideal approach. I believe it to be much cleaner it also uses between which i would like to incorporate if possible.

```
resp = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('domain').eq(domain) and Key('time_stamp').between(start,end),
            ProjectionExpression= 'time_stamp,event_type,country,tablet,mobile,desktop')


ERROR: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: 
Query condition missed key schema element: domain
```

Here is the second approach that I took. It appeared more often in docs and other stack questions that I found. Yet, I am still getting an error.

```
resp = table.query(
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#nd': 'domain',
            '#nts': 'time_stamp'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':vd': domain,
            ':vts': start,
            },
            KeyConditionExpression='(#nd = :vd) AND (#nts > :vts)',
            ProjectionExpression= 'time_stamp,event_type,country,tablet,mobile,desktop')

ERROR: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: 
One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type
```

I believe this error may be related to the data type of time_stamp being a string and not the Decimal() format that dynamo uses to represent numbers.

Comment: Did you figure this out? This is a top hit on google and looks like basically the same issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `&` not `and`.

```
resp = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('domain').eq(domain) & Key('time_stamp').between(start,end),
            ProjectionExpression= 'time_stamp,event_type,country,tablet,mobile,desktop')
```

[This is where the AWS docs say this, but it's kind of buried in there.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning)